# Multi-File Class Implementation Cpp

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm trying to implement a multi-file class, but I'm VERY confused in "how to do".

I've declared this class in the main file and it works, but now I'm trying make it appart from main file.

I got these doubts:

1-) I've a constructor in my class, so when I declare it on .cpp file I will declare a constructor inside a constructor???? sounds confusing..

2-) If the function in the .cpp file uses a global variable/vector declared in main file, I need to declare it using Extern??

3-) Need I to #include every lib necessaries to the functions on .cpp??

I can't tell the error I've got cuz every time it's a different one, some times I get the error:

```
error: 'DataReading' has not been declared|
```

I'll be really thankful for any help :)

First I will show the entire class that was working on main, be aware to the constructor (I will replace some codes with "//code code" to shorten it)

```
class DataReading
{
private:
    string word;
    string line;
    string temp;
public:
    DataReading(string wd) : word(wd)
    {}
    void ReadLineByLine()
    {
        //code code
    }

    void searchword()
    {
        //code code
    }
    int check_data()
    {
        if ((Names.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)) ||(WellTypes.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)) || (Positions.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (WellsRadius.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (Skins.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (ControlTypes.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (Pressures.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)))
        {
            //code code
        }
    }
```

So I will show what I tried, first the .h file:

```
#ifndef DATAREADING_H
#define DATAREADING_H


class DataReading
{
    public:
        DataReading(std::string wd);
        void ReadLineByLine();
        void searchword();
        int check_data();

    private:
        std::string word;
        std::string line;
        std::string temp;
};

#endif // DATAREADING_H
```

Now the .cpp file shortened:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

extern vector <string> Names;                              // Cria vetores necessários
extern vector <string> WellTypes;
extern vector <string> Positions;
extern vector <string> WellsRadius;
extern vector <string> Skins;
extern vector <string> ControlTypes;
extern vector <string> Pressures;
/*extern struct StructReading                                 //Estrutura para ler os dados do Reservatório
{
    string Variavel;
    double Valor;
}
extern vector <StructReading> DadosDeEntrada;*/

DataReading::DataReading(string wd) 
{
    DataReading(string wd) : word(wd)
    {}
}

void DataReading::ReadLineByLine()
    {
        //code code
    }

void DataReading::searchword()
    {
        //code code
    }

int DataReading::check_data()
    {
        if ((Names.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)) ||(WellTypes.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)) || (Positions.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (WellsRadius.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (Skins.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (ControlTypes.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1))|| (Pressures.size() != (DadosDeEntrada[7].Valor+1)))
        {
           //code code
        }
    }
```

PS: I need to use the struct in .cpp file but don't know how import this.

Answer (score 0):

datareading.h

```
#ifndef DATAREADING_H_INCLUDED
#define DATAREADING_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class DataReading
{
private:
    std::string word;
    std::string line;
    std::string temp;
public:
    DataReading(std::string const & wd);
    void ReadLineByLine();
    void searchword();
    int check_data();
};

#endif /* DATAREADING_H_INCLUDED */
```

datareading.cpp

```
#include "datareading.h"

DataReading::DataReading(std::string const & wd)
: word{ wd }
{}

void DataReading::ReadLineByLine()
{
    //code code
}

void DataReading::searchword()
{
    //code code
}
int DataReading::check_data()
{
    //code code
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "datareading.h"

int main()
{
    DataReading dr{"foo"};
}
```

You shouldn't use global variables, though.

"PS: I need to use the struct in .cpp file but don't know how import this."
Declare the struct in a header file of its own and include that everywhere you use the structure.

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know how to express my gratitude!
I got some questions, why do you changed the "()" by "{}"
Can I write like this?
`DataReading::DataReading(std::string const & wd) : word(wd)
    {}`

Comment: Writing initializations with curly brackets is a habit i picked up since C+11. You should find a lot of information about it by searching for **uniform initialization c++** on the web. About the global variables: in your question you stated that those were declared in the "main file" now you say they are declared within `main()`. You should not use global variables. Instead use local variables and pass (const) references to them to functions/classes that uses them.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, they are not in the Main! Thanks for the advice, I will try it. I've noticed that you just Included the "datareading.h" on .cpp file but is not necessary other includes as <iostream> and the `using namespace std;` line code on .h file??

Comment: `<string>` is already included in `datareading.h` which is included in `datareading.cpp` so the contents of `<string>` is also present in `datareading.cpp` when the preprocessor is done. Which files you have to include depends on what your `//code code` is. You shouldn't use `using namespace` in header files.

Comment: so I need to use the "includes" and the "namespace" in the `datareading.cpp`?

Comment: if you use any symbols defined in some header file within `datareading.cpp` you have to include that header file. You should look up what using a namespace means and then decide wheter to use it or not.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, I've tried declare the vectors/structs as local variable in .h to use in .cpp but I don't know how to pass by reference to the main function where I'm using the class.
I need to declare as private or public variable (or can be both)??
How I pass by reference a variable that isn't declared in that file?
I need to declare the Struct in private/public space on class or outside of the class?

Comment: "I've tried declare the vectors/structs as local variable in .h" if you declare a variable in a header file on file scope it is a global variable. in fact, it gets redefined in every .cpp you include the header in. Local variables are defined at function scope.